# How to get time or percentage from CCProgressTimer in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, timer, cocos2d-iphone, progress-bar

I've implemented a bar to show the time remaining to the player in a game. If the time goes to zero, I want to set the wrong result with an if cycle. But how to get the percentage at a certain instant? How can i recognize if the bar is empty? Thank You

```
CCProgressFromTo *to1 = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:MaxTime from:100 to:0];
bar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithFile:@"barra.png"];
bar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeHorizontalBarLR;
[bar setPosition:ccp(size.width - 250 , size.height - 18)];
float per= ?????

if (per==0)
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(wrong) withObject:nil];
}
```

Comment: CCProgressTimer has a percentage property, how about that?

Comment: I've read somewhere something like that..but I haven't find nothing... getPercentage or similar.. is it possible?

Comment: look in the api reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this (cocos2d version 2.x). The sprite is a horizontal slider track, and the settings on the progress timer will give you a 'full at 100' going right to left bar, empty at 0.

```
    _pt = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"slider_track.png"]];
    CCProgressFromTo *ft = [CCProgressFromTo actionWithDuration:20 from:100 to:0];
    _pt.position= ccp(kScreenWidth/2, kScreenHeight/2);
    _pt.type=kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
    _pt.reverseDirection= NO;
    _pt.midpoint=ccp(0,1);
    _pt.barChangeRate= ccp(1,0);
    [self addChild:_pt];
    [_pt runAction:ft];
    [self schedule:@selector(watchProgressTimer:) interval:1.0];


-(void) watchProgressTimer:(ccTime) dt {
    MPLOG(@"Progress timer percentage is %f ",_pt.percentage);
    if(_pt.percentage==0.f){
        [self unschedule:@selector(watchProgressTimer:)];
        [self removeChild:_pt cleanup:YES];
        [self dowhateverYouDoAtZero] ;
    }
}

-(void) dowhateverYouDoAtZero{
    // your business logic for expired timer here
    MPLOG(@"Bang , time's up !!!");
}
```

gives this on the console

-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 95.254395 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 90.169464 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 85.168495 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 79.918976 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 74.670525 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 69.669678 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 64.667480 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 59.419960 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 54.168777 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 49.167599 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 43.920143 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 38.919609 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 33.919609 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 28.917831 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 23.669678 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 18.667908 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 13.418236 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 8.168266 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 3.167412 
-[MPGameSequencer watchProgressTimer:] : Progress timer percentage is 0.000000 
-[MPGameSequencer dowhateverYouDoAtZero] : Bang , time's up !!!

Answer (score 0):

In cocos2d-x you get presentage like this

```
bar->getPresentage();
```